# html phone link dont work in nativescript webview

Tags: nativescript

i creat an application based in webview where i have a link (a) with tel: like this 
     `<a href="tel:1231233132" >`  ; 
but when i click in ;but nothing happens.

XML :

```
       <Page class="page"
    navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
    actionBarHidden="true">



     <GridLayout>
        <WebView row="1" loaded="onWebViewLoaded" id="myWebView" src="https://xxxx.xxx" />
    </GridLayout>
    </Page>
```

I dont know what i have to do.

Comment: Is it iOS or Android you are facing the issue with?

Comment: i need it in IOS Platform

Comment: Have you added `tel` to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your `info.plist`?

Comment: thank you for your answer ;
Yes i did <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
    <string>tel</string>
    <string>telprompt</string>
 </array>